# WPF ToolTip lookalike

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm looking for method to create something that looks like WPF ToolTip, but behaves just like any normal element drawn on canvas. Tooltips are problematic, when they are forced to appear not over the mouse and that's what I'm trying to do. Force them to appear in certain situations.

I tried using adorners, but unfortunately they don't work with Shapes class I'm using.

Comment: Maybe just create a custom popup.

Comment: I'm considering this, but could they be platform dependent? That's what I'm looking for. I have ToolTips that work in  normal way on mouse hoover, but i would like to have second element that looks exactly the same. This element would be shown programatically, but from UI point of view I want them to be indistinguishable.

Comment: from Popup documentation  "When Popup is displayed on the screen, it does not reposition itself if its parent is repositioned." that is exactly the same problem I have with ToolTip. It doesn't move, when i move the window

Comment: You could always bind popup's position to window's position, but that's not the most elegant way to do this.

Comment: @FCin, using events? Or is there any other way to do it?